# If else endif PHP trouble

Tags: php, if-statement

- EDITED ****

Hello I am new to PHP and trying to figure out a hack for a Joomla module.

For some reason the 'else' statement is not working. I don't understand why...

```
        <? if (KRequest::get('get.view', 'string') != 'event'  || isset($module)) : ?>
        <? $desc = $event->description; ?>
        <? $desc = preg_replace("/\{[^\)]+\}/","", $desc) ?>

        <? $desc = substr(strip_tags($desc, '<p><ul><li><b><i><strong><br>'), 0, 180)?>
        <? if (strlen($desc) == 180) $desc .= '...'; ?>
        <div itemprop="description" class="ohanah-event-short-description">
        <?=$desc?>
        </div>
    <? else : ?>
    <!--here is where I want to end it --!>No description.


        <?
        $description = $event->description;

        // Create temporary article
        $item =& JTable::getInstance('content');
        $item->parameters = new JParameter('');
        $item->text = $description;

        $joomlaVersion = JVersion::isCompatible('1.6.0') ? '1.6' : '1.5';
        if ($joomlaVersion == '1.5') { 
            $results = JFactory::getApplication()->triggerEvent('onPrepareContent', array (&$item, &$params, 1));
        } else {
            $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
            JPluginHelper::importPlugin('content');
            $results = $dispatcher->trigger('onContentPrepare', array ('com_content.article', &$item, &$params, 1));
        }   
        $description = $item->text;     
        ?>
        <div style="display:none"><span itemprop="name"><?=$event->title?></span></div>
        <div itemprop="description" class="full-description">
        <?=$description?>
        </div>
    <? endif ?>
```

Comment: I don't see any `endif`s here. Are you sure this is all the relevant code?

Comment: "not working" is not a description of expected vs observed behaviour, and your post's title is absolutely rubbish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braces are wrong. Should be like this (or similar - not sure about where you need $desc):

```
if (strlen($desc) == 180)
{
    $desc .= '...';
    echo '<div itemprop="description" class="short-description">';
    echo $desc;
    echo '</div>';
}
else
{
    echo 'No description.';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that all your code?  You need the closing endif.

That said, consider the curly brace syntax, I find it much easier to avoid errors with.

On a side note, you don't have to have `<?php` and `?>` on every line when every line is PHP, you can leave the php block open across several lines.

```
<?php
if (...) {
    // stuff
} else {
    // other stuff
}
?>
```

If I understand your code flow, it would look like this

```
<?php
if (KRequest::get('get.view', 'string') != 'event'  || isset($module)) {
    $desc = $event->description;
    $desc = preg_replace("/\{[^\)]+\}/","", $desc)

    $desc = substr(strip_tags($desc, '<p><ul><li><b><i><strong><br>'), 0, 180)
    if (strlen($desc) == 180) {
        $desc .= '...';
    }
?>
    <div itemprop="description" class="short-description">
<?php echo $desc; ?>
    </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    No description.
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I like your gravatar, even if it _is_ a rip-off.

Comment: You'd think that right?  But we are talking about a Joomla coder.  Ewww! *Shudder*

Comment: Sorry, I missed off the full section from the original code.

The full thing is there now....

Answer (score 0):

I'm just kind of guessing, but don't you need to remove the semicolon in the IF statement to tell the parser that there is still an else block there, i.e.

```
if (strlen($desc) == 180) $desc .= '...'
```

Comment: No. I believe the `else` is supposed to go with the _first_ `if`, from studying the logic. The second `if` just a (broken) attempt to truncate and prettify a long description (it forgets to truncate)